# Looking for a regex pattern, passing that pattern to a script, and replacing the pattern with the output of the script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

For every time the pattern shows up (In this example the case of a 2 digit number) I want to pass that pattern to a script and replace that pattern with the output of a script.

I'm using sed an example of what it should look like would be

```
echo 'siedi87sik65owk55dkd' | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]/.\/script.sh/g'
```

Right now this returns

```
siedi./script.shsik./script.showk./script.shdkd
```

But I would like it to return

```
siedi!!!87!!!sik!!!65!!!owk!!!55!!!dkd
```

This is what is in ./script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "!!!$1!!!"
```

It has to be replaced with the output. In this example I know I could just use a normal sed substitution but I don't want that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Anything else, even if it can be done, requires arcane language constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and are used today purely for the mental exercise. Your problem is not a simple substitution so you shouldn't try to use sed to solve it.

You're going to want something like:

```
awk '{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/[0-9]{2}/) ) {
        tgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        cmd = "./script.sh " tgt
        if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0) {
            tgt = line
        }
        close(cmd)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) tgt
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head tail
}'
```

e.g. using an `echo` in place of your `script.sh` command:

```
$ echo 'siedi87sik65owk55dkd' |
awk '{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/[0-9]{2}/) ) {
        tgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        cmd = "echo !!!" tgt "!!!"
        if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0) {
            tgt = line
        }
        close(cmd)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) tgt
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head tail
}'
siedi!!!87!!!sik!!!65!!!owk!!!55!!!dkd
```

Comment: What is the line after getline? Why do you set tgt = line. 
Also why do you have to close(cmd)

Comment: I'm replacing the original value of `tgt` with the result of `cmd | getline` only if `cmd | getline` succeeded, otherwise I'm leaving `tgt` with it's original value. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fPipe and http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for details on how/when to use getline (from a pipe).

Answer (score 2):

Ed's [awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41798207/3266847) is obviously the way to go here.

For fun, I tried to come up with a sed solution, and here is (a convoluted GNU sed) one that takes the pattern and the script to be run as parameters; the input is either read from standard input (i.e., you can pipe to it) or from a file supplied as the third argument.

For your example, we'd have `infile` with contents

```
siedi87sik65owk55dkd
siedi11sik22owk33dkd
```

(two lines to demonstrate how this works for multiple lines), then `script` with contents

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "!!!${1}!!!"
```

and finally the solution script itself, `so`. Usage is

```
./so pattern script [input]
```

where *`pattern`* is an extended regular expression as understood by GNU sed (with the `-r` option), *`script`* is the name of the command you want to run for each match, and the optional *`input`* is the name of the input file if input is not standard input.

For your example, this would be

```
./so '[[:digit:]]{2}' script infile
```

or, as a filter,

```
cat infile | ./so '[[:digit:]]{2}' script
```

with output

```
siedi!!!87!!!sik!!!65!!!owk!!!55!!!dkd
siedi!!!11!!!sik!!!22!!!owk!!!33!!!dkd
```

This is what `so` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat=$1                      # The pattern to match
script=$2                   # The command to run for each pattern
infile=${3:-/dev/stdin}     # Read from standard input if not supplied

# Use sed and have $pattern and $script expand to the supplied parameters
sed -r "
    :build_loop                        # Label to loop back to
    h                                  # Copy pattern space to hold space
    s/.*($pat).*/.\/\"$script\" \1/    # (1) Extract last match and prepare command
    # Replace pattern space with output of command
    e
    G                                  # (2) Append hold space to pattern space
    s/(.*)$pat(.*)/\1~~~\2/            # (3) Replace last match of pattern with ~~~
    /\n[^\n]*$pat[^\n]*$/b build_loop  # Loop if string contains match
    :fill_loop                         # Label for second loop
    s/(.*\n)(.*)\n([^\n]*)~~~([^\n]*)$/\1\3\2\4/ # (4) Replace last ~~~
    t fill_loop                        # Loop if there was a replacement
    s/(.*)\n(.*)~~~(.*)$/\2\1\3/       # (5) Final ~~~ replacement
" < "$infile"
```

The sed command works with two loops. The first one copies the pattern space to the hold space, then removes everything but the last match from the pattern space and prepares the command to be run. After the substitution with (1) in its comment, the pattern space looks like this:

```
./script 55
```

The `e` command (a GNU extension) then replaces the pattern space with the output of this command. After this, `G` appends the hold space to the pattern space (2). The pattern space now looks like this:

```
!!!55!!!
siedi87sik65owk55dkd
```

The substitution at (3) replaces the last match with a string hopefully not equal to the pattern and we get

```
!!!55!!!
siedi87sik65owk~~~dkd
```

The loop repeats if the last line of the pattern space still has a match for the pattern. After three loops, the pattern space looks like this:

```
!!!87!!!
!!!65!!!
!!!55!!!
siedi~~~sik~~~owk~~~dkd
```

The second loop now replaces the last `~~~` with the second to last line of the pattern space with substitution (4). The command uses lots of "not a newline" (`[^\n]`) to make sure we're not pulling the wrong replacement for `~~~`.

Because of the way command (4) is written, the loop ends with one last substitution to go, so before command (5), we have this pattern space:

```
!!!87!!!
siedi~~~sik!!!65!!!owk!!!55!!!dkd
```

Command (5) is a simpler version of command (4), and after it, the output is as desired.

This seems to be fairly robust and can deal with spaces in the name of the script to be run as long as it's properly quoted when calling:

```
./so '[[:digit:]]{2}' 'my script' infile
```

This would fail if

- The input file contains `~~~` (solvable by replacing all occurrences at the start, putting them back at the end)
- The output of `script` contains `~~~`
- The pattern contains `~~~`

i.e., the solution very much depends on `~~~` being unique.

---

<sub>Because nobody asked: `so` as a one-liner.</sub>

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -re ":b;h;s/.*($1).*/.\/\"$2\" \1/;e" -e "G;s/(.*)$1(.*)/\1~~~\2/;/\n[^\n]*$1[^\n]*$/bb;:f;s/(.*\n)(.*)\n([^\n]*)~~~([^\n]*)$/\1\3\2\4/;tf;s/(.*)\n(.*)~~~(.*)$/\2\1\3/" < "${3:-/dev/stdin}"
```

<sub>Still works!</sub>

Comment: Ed calls this a "mental exercise" – which is very accurate. (Mental exercises are fun, though!)

Comment: And the beauty of it is no-one can understand it to tell you if there's any errors in it :-). It might launch skynet on the 2nd Sunday in March and we'd never know. Until March of course.... :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I hope somebody subjects this to rigorous testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

A **conceptually simpler multi-utility solution**:

Using *GNU* utilities:

```
echo 'siedi87sik65owk55dkd' | 
  sed 's|[0-9]\{2\}|$(./script.sh &)|g' |
    xargs -d'\n' -I% sh -c 'echo '\"%\"
```

Using *BSD* utilities (also works with GNU utilities):

```
echo 'siedi87sik65owk55dkd' | 
  sed 's|[0-9]\{2\}|$(./script.sh &)|g' | tr '\n' '\0' |
    xargs -0 -I% sh -c 'echo '\"%\"
```

The idea is to use `sed` to translate the tokens of interest lexically into a string containing shell command substitutions that invoke the target script with the token, and then pass the result to the shell for evaluation.

Note:

- Any embedded `"` and `$` characters in the input must be `\`-escaped.
- `xargs -d'\n'` (GNU) and `tr '\n' '\0'` / `xargs -0` (BSD) are only needed to correctly preserve *whitespace* in the input - if that is not needed, the following POSIX-compliant solution will do:

  ```
  echo 'siedi87sik65owk55dkd' | 
    sed 's|[0-9]\{2\}|$(./script.sh &)|g' | tr '\n' '\0' |
      xargs -I% sh -c 'printf "%s\n" '\"%\"
  ```